# XPATH inside IMPORTXML with apostrophe in query

Tags: google-sheets

The issue is how to find the right way to search for string which includes an apostrophe. The string is a `title` of an `a` tag from imported URL.

So the starting point is:
`=IMPORTXML("http://www.some.com";"//a[contains(@title,'Mac's Issue')]")`
which of course does not work because of the raw apostrophe inside. How to escape this character in the right way? I've tried using `""` and `\` but with no success.

Edit: sample sheet with such issue https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGaAOpUeF8jZlL6La6zDw9nlcidOqA1apBt18mPUH7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems like the engine replaces `CHAR(39)` with an actual apostrophe and then it is back to the original issue.

Comment: `&#39;` also doesn't work because it's translated to apostrophe before query.

Comment: It is only due to the `'` because cutting the part of string with that character from the query goes to the rightful execution. But it's not the solution unfortunately :)

Comment: The returned error is `Error: Imported XML content cannot be parsed.`

Comment: The sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGaAOpUeF8jZlL6La6zDw9nlcidOqA1apBt18mPUH7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately the related topic doesn't show solution or I can't find it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

XPath has a concat function, this should help:

`//code[contains(.,concat('"',"Mac","'","s Issue"))]`

The formula is:

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.some.com";
"//code[contains(.,concat('""',""Mac"",""'"",""s Issue""))]")`

Reference:

- [XPath functions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)

---

You may try using double quotes instead of single:

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.some.com";"//code[contains(.,""Mac's Issue"")]")`

Ths string is in double quotes now: "Mac's Issue".

Note: each double quote is used twice because the argument of a function is a string and it is stored in a double quotes itself.

Comment: Thank you, Max! But as stated below:

It is useful for this particular situation but does not really solve the problem :) Actually only replacing `//code[contains(.,'Mac's Issue')]` with `//code[contains(.,""Mac's Issue"")]` do the work. But! The problem returns when the query (value we search for) includes `'` and `"`.

Comment: @friedman, that's right, I've found another solution, please see the edit.

Comment: That's the winner! Thank you!

Comment: Nice solution! Also I would like to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, how about this workaround? This sample uses `=IMPORTXML("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863529/xpath-inside-importxml-with-apostrophe-in-query";"//code[contains(.,'Mac's Issue')]")` of your sample spreadsheet.

1. Put `//code[contains(text(), "Mac's Issue")]` to "A1".

   - `//code[contains(.,'Mac's Issue')]` occurs an error.
2. Put `=IMPORTXML("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863529/xpath-inside-importxml-with-apostrophe-in-query",A1)` to "A2".

#### Result :

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: It is useful for this particular situation but does not really solve the problem :) Actually only replacing `//code[contains(.,'Mac's Issue')]` with `//code[contains(.,""Mac's Issue"")]` do the work. But! The problem returns when the query (value we search for) includes `'` and `"`.